# How can I get a Sql Server Bulk Insert to work when using a 'þ' as a FieldDelimiter?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Executing the following statement against sql server 2005 is failing.

```
BULK INSERT aTest FROM 'G:/aTest.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='þ',ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

The error is this

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

If I change the FIELDTERMINATOR to a comma and I change the data file to have a comma it works as expected.

Here's my data file (aTest.txt):

```
1þfirst
2þtwo
```

Comment: Copying your aTest.txt and pasting it into notepad it worked for me with no errors using the BULK INSERT statement you supplied. Maybe your file has some sort of hidden characters in it?

Comment: Same test, same results as @Kevin. ?Flip the slash to backslash in your FROM clause?

Comment: @KevinDahl Seems my data file was utf-8 encoded. Changing it to ascii fixed the problem. Your comment tipped me off to this because I was using a different editor and then changed to notepad. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my specific question/problem was to make sure that the data file is ascii encoded because I wanted to use 'þ' as a field terminator. My data file happened to be utf-8 encoded which caused the terminator to be ignored.